# Using trigger on view depending value change

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a view like this

```
CREATE VIEW cust_bonus
AS

SELECT sale_id, customer, saletotal, saletotal*10/100 AS bonus, 1 type FROM sales

UNION ALL
SELECT doc_id, customer, 0, bonus, 1 type FROM bonusplus

UNION ALL
SELECT doc_id, customer, 0, bonus, -1 type FROM bonusminus
```

I need a trigger for inserting bonus and customer info to another table when value of bonus column changes. For example SELECT SUM(bonus*type) from custbonus returns 50 then I insert a row to sales or bonus plus-minus. Then the same statement returns 60 or etc. I don't want to write 3 triggers for each table on this view

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us (in the title), it comes across as rude, and could easily attract downvotes and/or close votes.

Comment: As for what you're asking, what have you tried so far? Why didn't it work? Also, SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for some time now; it's long past time getting to a supported version.

Comment: ah sorry ,I thought titles will be seem better with caps lock

Comment: I can only write 3 different triggers for each table. I can't find  any other way.

Comment: I suggest your data model and your business logic is very flawed. A bonus is like an account balance. It "accumulates" over time as <something> changes. Generally these are transactions of a specific type that occur from a particular point in time. At another point in time, that bonus is awarded or paid and the clock starts again. Perhaps that period basis is implicit since you intend to purge rows from the 3 mentioned tables - but that seems highly unlikely. And yes - you can write many triggers of all types for a table. Not common but it can be done.

Comment: *"I thought titles will be seem better with caps lock"* no, it's just rude. Typing in all capitals comes across like you are SHOUTING, which really isn't needed. *"I can't find any other way"* What didn't work when you tried creating the trigger on the `VIEW` then? Show us that attempt.

Answer (score 0):

you can try, like this in **instead of UPDATE**

```
IF UPDATE(bonus)
BEGIN
    print 'do it something'
END

-- end todo update statement
```